# A question about basis for $\ker \varphi ^{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector spaces , and let $\varphi:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator such that

$$\begin{matrix}
  \mathbf{a_{1}},& \mathbf{a_{2}}, & \mathbf{a_{3}} &  &  & &\text{ is a basis for 
} \ker\varphi  ,\\ 
  \mathbf{a_{1}},&  \mathbf{a_{2}},&  \mathbf{a_{3}};&  \mathbf{b_{1}},& \mathbf{b_{2}} &  &\text{ is a basis for 
}\ker{\varphi}^{2} ,\\
 \mathbf{a_{1}}, & \mathbf{a_{2}}, &  \mathbf{a_{3}};&  \mathbf{b_{1}},&  \mathbf{b_{2}}; &\mathbf{c_{1}} &\text{ is a basis for 
}\ker{\varphi}^{3} .
 \end{matrix}$$
Obviously, $\mathbb{span}\{\varphi(\mathbf{b_{1}}),\varphi(\mathbf{b_{2}})\}\subseteq \mathbb{span}\{\mathbf{a_{1}},\mathbf{a_{2}},\mathbf{a_{3}}\}.$
Can we proof that $\mathbb{span}\{\varphi(\mathbf{c_{1}})\}\subseteq \mathbb{span}\{\mathbf{b_{1}},\mathbf{b_{2}}\} ?$

---

$$\varphi(\mathbf{c_{1}})\in \ker\varphi^2=\ker\varphi \bigoplus \mathbb{span}\{\mathbf{b_{1}},\mathbf{b_{2}}\},$$
$$\varphi(\mathbf{c_{1}})+\ker\varphi\in \ker\varphi^2 / \ker \varphi \text{(a quotient space);}$$
$$\ker\varphi^2/ \ker \varphi =\mathbb{span}\{\mathbf{b_{1}}+\ker \varphi,\mathbf{b_{2}}+\ker \varphi\},$$ $$\mathbb{span}\{\mathbf{b_{1}},\mathbf{b_{2}}\}\cong \ker\varphi^2/ \ker \varphi \text{(the symbol} \cong \text{means } \textit{isomorphism}).$$

But how to proof
$$\varphi(\mathbf{c_{1}})=k_1\mathbf{b_{1}}+k_2\mathbf{b_{2}}?$$

Comment: I don't think that this statement holds. Maybe you should think about $\phi$ with $\phi(a_1)=0$, $\phi(b_1)=a_1$, $\phi(c_1)=a_1+b_1$. This would suffice all your assumptions. Usually, you try to construct such vectors as you want them to be by first picking $c_1$, then obtaining $b_1$, choosing $b_2$ and obtaining $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1&   0&  -1&  1&  0\\
  -4&   1&  -3&  2& 1\\
  -2&  -1&  0&  1& 1\\
  -3&  -1&  -3&  4& 1\\
  -8&  -2&  -7&  5& 4
\end{pmatrix},
\det(\lambda I_{5}-A)=(\lambda-2)^{5}.$$
Set
$$B=A-2I_{5}=\begin{pmatrix}
   -1&   0&  -1&  1&  0\\
  -4&   -1&  -3&  2& 1\\
  -2&  -1&  -2&  1& 1\\
  -3&  -1&  -3&  2& 1\\
  -8&  -2&  -7&  5& 2
\end{pmatrix},$$

then
$$\ker{B}=\text{span}\{\mathbf{x_4}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\
 -1\\
 1\\
 1\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\mathbf{x_{5}}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\
 1\\
 0\\
 0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\};$$

$$\ker{B^2}=\text{span}\{\mathbf{x_4},\mathbf{x_{5}};\mathbf{x_{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\
 1\\
 0\\
 0\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\mathbf{x_{3}}=\begin{pmatrix}
 -1\\
 0\\
 1\\
 0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\};$$

$$\ker{B^3}=\text{span}\{\mathbf{x_4},\mathbf{x_{5}};\mathbf{x_{2}},\mathbf{x_{3}};\mathbf{x_{1}}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1\\
 0\\
 0\\
 0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\}.$$

$$\begin{matrix}
  \mathbf{x_{4}},& \mathbf{x_{5}}, & &  &  & &\text{ is a basis for 
} \ker{B} ,\\ 
  \mathbf{x_{4}},&  \mathbf{x_{5}};&  \mathbf{x_{2}},&  \mathbf{x_{3}}&  &  &\text{ is a basis for 
}\ker{B}^{2} ,\\
 \mathbf{x_{4}}, & \mathbf{x_{5}}; &  \mathbf{x_{2}},&  \mathbf{x_{3}};&  \mathbf{x_{1}} & &\text{ is a basis for 
}\ker{B}^{3} .
 \end{matrix}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|cc} B^{2}(\mathbf{x_1})& B(\mathbf{x_2})& B(\mathbf{x_3})& \mathbf{x_4}& \mathbf{x_5}& \\ B(\mathbf{x_1})& \mathbf{x_2}&  \mathbf{x_3}&  &  & \\ \mathbf{x_1}&  & &  &  & \\  
\end{array}$$

Obviously,$$\mathbb{span}\{B(\mathbf{x_{1}})\}\nsubseteqq \mathbb{span}\{\mathbf{x_{2}},\mathbf{x_{3}}\}\quad !$$